# Saving system categories from my controller on TYPO3 v10

Tags: php, model-view-controller, typo3, typo3-10.x

I have an IdeaModel and an IdeaController.

One property of my model is "category" (with it's proper column on db) and I want to save the uid of the a system category in this column. (the backend form works with no problem)

I've made a frontend form for the frontend user to create an Idea with a category. This form sends an IdeaModel object to my IdeaController

But when I do `$this->ideaRepository->add($idea);` I get an error saying `Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'category' at row 1`.

Is it because of my IdeaModel property is an int and it should be a Category type variable? Or an ObjectStorage?
I have been trying with that but I don't know how to handle ObjectStorage? I don't know much about typo3 yet. If you know whats the problem or have a useful guide about this I'll be grateful.

IdeaModel.php

```
<?php

namespace Edu\EduIdeas\Domain\Model;

use TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\DomainObject\AbstractEntity;

class Idea extends AbstractEntity
{
    /**
     * title
     * 
     * @var string
     */
    protected $title = '';

    /**
     * description
     * 
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = '';

    /**
     * category
     * 
     * @var int
     */
    protected $category = '';

    /**
     * status
     * 
     * @var int
     */
    protected $status = '';

    /**
     * user
     * 
     * @var int
     */
    protected $user = '';

    /**
     * likes
     * 
     * @var int
     */
    protected $likes = '';

    /**
     * Sets the title
     * 
     * @param string $title
     * @return void
     */
    public function setTitle(string $title): void
    {
        $this->title = $title;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the title
     * 
     * @return string $title
     */
    public function getTitle(): string
    {
        return $this->title;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the description
     * 
     * @param string $description
     * @return void
     */
    public function setDescription(string $description): void
    {
        $this->description = $description;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the description
     * 
     * @return string $description
     */
    public function getDescription(): string
    {
        return $this->description;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the category
     * 
     * @param int $category
     * @return void
     */
    public function setCategory(int $category): void
    {
        $this->category = $category;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the category
     * 
     * @return int $category
     */
    public function getCategory(): int
    {
        return $this->category;
    }
    
    /**
     * Sets the status
     * 
     * @param int $status
     */
    public function setStatus(int $status): void
    {
        $this->status = $status;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the status
     * 
     * @return int $status
     */
    public function getStatus(): int
    {
        return $this->status;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the user
     * 
     * @param int $user
     */
    public function setUser(int $user): void
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the user
     * 
     * @return int $user
     */
    public function getUser(): int
    {
        return $this->user;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the likes
     * 
     * @param int $likes
     */
    public function setLikes(int $likes): void
    {
        $this->likes = $likes;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the likes
     * 
     * @return int $likes
     */
    public function getLikes(): int
    {
        return $this->likes;
    }
}
```

IdeaController.php

```
<?php

namespace Edu\EduIdeas\Controller;

use TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Annotation as Extbase;
use TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\Controller\ActionController;
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility;
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Database\ConnectionPool;
use Edu\EduIdeas\Domain\Model\Idea;
use Edu\EduIdeas\Domain\Repository\IdeaRepository;
/***
 * For the full copyright and license information, please read the
 * LICENSE.txt file that was distributed with this source code.
 *
 *  (c) 2019 
 *
 ***/
/**
 * IdeasController
 */
class IdeasController extends ActionController
{
    /**
     * Inject the idea repository
     *
     * @param Edu\EduIdeas\Domain\Repository\IdeaRepository $ideaRepository
     */
    private $ideaRepository;

    public function injectIdeaRepository(IdeaRepository $ideaRepository)
    {
        $this->ideaRepository = $ideaRepository;
    }

    /**
     * action list
     * 
     * @return string An HTML with a list of posted aideas
     */
    public function listAction()
    {
        $ideas = $this->ideaRepository->findAll();
        $this->view->assign('ideas', $ideas);
    }
    /**
     * @param \Edu\EduIdeas\Domain\Model\Idea $idea The new Idea object
     * @return string An HTML form for creating a new idea
     * @Extbase\IgnoreValidation("newIdea")
     */
    public function newAction(Idea $newIdea = null)
    {
        $queryBuilder = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ConnectionPool::class)->getQueryBuilderForTable('tt_content');
        $categories = $queryBuilder->select('title', 'uid')->from('sys_category')->where($queryBuilder->expr()->eq('parent', $queryBuilder->createNamedParameter(7)))
        ->execute()->fetchAll();
        $this->view->assign('newIdea', $newIdea);
        $this->view->assign('categories', $categories);
    }
    /**
     * Creates a new Idea
     *
     * @param Idea $idea The idea to save on db
     * @return void
     */
    public function createAction(Idea $idea)
    {
        // TODO access protection
        $idea->setStatus(1);
        $idea->setUser($GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->user['uid']);
        $this->ideaRepository->add($idea);
        $this->redirect('list');
    }
}
```

```
'category' => [
            'label' => 'LLL:EXT:hebo_ideas/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:hk_ideas_idea.category',
            'config' => [
                'type' => 'select',
                'renderType' => 'selectTree',
                'treeConfig' => [
                    'parentField' => 'parent',
                    'rootUid' => 7,
                    'appearance' => [
                        'showHeader' => false,
                        'expandAll' => true,
                    ],
                ],
                'foreign_table' => 'sys_category',
                'foreign_table_where' => ' AND (sys_category.sys_language_uid = 0 OR sys_category.l10n_parent = 0) ORDER BY sys_category.sorting',
                'size' => 10,
                'minitems' => 0,
                'maxitems' => 1,
            ]
         ],
```

PD: It is an int

[image]

[image]

Answer (score -1):

The error means you are trying to insert an empty string to an integer column. How to solve depends on the table structure. If the column is nullable, set the default value to `null`:

```
protected $category = null;
```

Or, if the column has some other default value, e.g. `0`, you can set it to that.
Otherwise you should explicitly provide a valid integer value before inserting:

```
$idea->setCategory($categoryId);
$this->ideaRepository->add($idea);
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I know, but IT IS an integer type... that's why is driving me crazy. Actually if I change my database type value for category from int to varchar it works, it saves this id number as a varchar I guess. So it is so clear that the problem would be the type of data, but when I dump the variable it clearly says integer. That's why I thought that may be is a typo3 thing.

Comment: Are you still getting the error for `category` column or for some other column now? Because other fields documented as integers are still empty strings.